# How can i do referal system in bot?

Tags: python

I use this in my code:

```
            get_id = message.text.split(' ')[-1] #get ref
            print(get_id) ###print /start or /start id
            ref_id = int(get_id)
            if get_id != usr_id[user_id]:
                query = "INSERT INTO refers (`usr_id`, `ref_ids`) VALUES (%s, %s);"
                cursor = connect.cursor()
                cursor.execute(query, (usr_id[user_id], ref_id))
                query_two = "UPDATE users SET invited = invited + 1 WHERE usr_id = %s"
                curs = connect.cursor()
                curs.execute(query_two, usr_id[user_id])
                connect.commit()
```

if i do get_id = message.text.split(' ')[1]
get

> out of range this

if [-1] then

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '/start'

get everytime. I dont know what can i do. Can somebody help me?

Comment: If the problem is in the message variable, you should tell us what's its value

Comment: What is message? Show us enough code to reproduce the problem!

Comment: /start id to be correctly like /start 100037284 (id here)

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '/start'` tells you the problem: You have the string `"/start"` and ask Python to convert this string to an integer. This cannot work.

Comment: Yes thanks. Thats string value, but how can i change to int? Or better way to get value from message.text?

Comment: if you may have `/start` or `/start id` then you should check `len(message.text.split(' '))` before you try to get `[1]` or even `[-1]` . If `len()` gives 1 then you have only `/start` and there is no sense to convert to `int`

Comment: len print 1 with /start and 2 with /start id

Comment: i cant understand what can i do with it now

Comment: @furas anyway i cant change that to int i must do it. How?

Comment: if you get only `/start` then there is no number which you could conver to `int` - and this is your mistake. When `len()`  gives `1` then skip rest of code.

Comment: @furas u are cool man! i couldnt do nothing and finally resolved this sht. Can you asnwer below post for i accept this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you may have `/start` or `/start id` then you should check `len(message.text.split(' '))` before you try to get `[1]` or even `[-1]`. If `len()` gives `1` then you have only `/start` and there is no number which you could convert to `int` and you should skip it or use some default value.

You may need also `try/except` because user may put text (ie. `Hello`) instead of number.

```
parts = message.text.split(' ')

if len(parts) < 2:
    print("WARNING: you forgot ID")
    return

try:
    ref_id = int(parts[1])
except ValueError:
    print("WARNING: ID has to be integer number")
    return

# ... rest ...
```